# Dockerising NodeJS application is not working

Tags: node.js, docker

I am dockerizing a Node JS application. First I created a Dockerfile with the following content inside the project root folder.

```
FROM node:14-alpine
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add nodejs
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
COPY . /
RUN cd /; npm install
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["node", "/server.js"]
```

I then created the server.js file in the project root folder too with the following content.

```
const http = require('http');

const host = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 4000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Hello World!');
});

server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log('Web server running at http://%s:%s',host,port );
});
```

Then I created the docker-compose.yaml file with the following content.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
```

Then I run `docker-compose up -d` command to spin up the environment. When I go to the localhost:4000 in the browser, I am getting the following error in the browser.

[image]

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the output of docker compose? Also, does it help if you add the command starting the app to the docker compose file?

Comment: This seems to work just fine when I run it locally.

Comment: I cleared all the docker images and containers and run the code again. It seems to be working now.